# How to prevent a window from minimizing?

Tags: c#, wpf, minimize

How can I prevent WPF window from minimizing when users clicks on show desktop button?

Comment: Why do you want to stop users from, you know, seeing their desktop?

Comment: I'm developing a desktop calender so it's like the background of window

Comment: possible duplicate of [Window "on desktop"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365094/window-on-desktop)

Comment: Perhaps a candidate to be a Sidebar/Gadgets app instead?  A standard window that refuses to get out of the way essentially breaks the user's computer.  What if there's a desktop icon they need to get to?

Comment: I got 2 answers! 1- You don't. 2- You close it, it won't minimize!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link will help you : [Get the minimize box click of a WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938924/get-the-minimize-box-click-of-a-wpf-window/938956#938956)

you need to catch the event and handle it yourself.

Edit : This method will alert you once the state is changed, so it might not be the "best" solution but it could work.

Comment: I tried using a timer to get the state but it works but it think it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Windows are not minimized when "Show Desktop" is issued. Instead the "WorkerW" and "Desktop" windows are brought to the foreground.

I ended up developing my own solution.
I scoured the internet for weeks trying to find an answer so I'm kind of proud of this one.

So what we do is use pinvoke to create a hook for the EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND window event.
This event triggers whenever the foreground window is changed.

Now what I noticed is when the "Show Desktop" command is issued, the WorkerW window class becomes foreground.

Note this WorkerW window is not the desktop and I confirmed the hwnd of this WorkerW window is not the Desktop hwnd.

So what we do is whenever the WorkerW window becomes the foreground, we set our "WPF Gadget Window" to be topmost!

Whenever a window other the WorkerW window becomes the foreground, we remove topmost from our "WPF Gadget Window".

If you want to take it a step further, you can uncomment out the part where I check if the new foreground window is also "PROGMAN", which is the Desktop window.

However, this will lead to your window becoming topmost if the user clicks their desktop on a different monitor. In my case, I did not want this behavior, but I figured some of you might.

Confirmed to work in Windows 10. Should work in older versions of Windows.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, ShowDesktop.WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder name, int count);
    }

    public static class ShowDesktop
    {
        private const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0u;
        private const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3u;

        private const string WORKERW = "WorkerW";
        private const string PROGMAN = "Progman";

        public static void AddHook(Window window)
        {
            if (IsHooked)
            {
                return;
            }

            IsHooked = true;

            _delegate = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventHook);
            _hookIntPtr = NativeMethods.SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, IntPtr.Zero, _delegate, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
            _window = window;
        }

        public static void RemoveHook()
        {
            if (!IsHooked)
            {
                return;
            }

            IsHooked = false;

            NativeMethods.UnhookWinEvent(_hookIntPtr.Value);

            _delegate = null;
            _hookIntPtr = null;
            _window = null;
        }

        private static string GetWindowClass(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder(32);
            NativeMethods.GetClassName(hwnd, _sb, _sb.Capacity);
            return _sb.ToString();
        }

        internal delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

        private static void WinEventHook(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
        {
            if (eventType == EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND)
            {
                string _class = GetWindowClass(hwnd);

                if (string.Equals(_class, WORKERW, StringComparison.Ordinal) /*|| string.Equals(_class, PROGMAN, StringComparison.Ordinal)*/ )
                {
                    _window.Topmost = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _window.Topmost = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool IsHooked { get; private set; } = false;

        private static IntPtr? _hookIntPtr { get; set; }

        private static WinEventDelegate _delegate { get; set; }

        private static Window _window { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change your window's parent to not be affected by Show Desktop. (as stated here: [Window "on desktop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365094/window-on-desktop/365171#365171))

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindowLoaded;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    private void MainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        var ProgmanHwnd = FindWindowEx(FindWindowEx(FindWindow("Progman", "Program Manager"), IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView",""), IntPtr.Zero,"SysListView32", "FolderView");
        SetParent(hwnd, ProgmanHwnd);
    }

}
```

Comment: Incorrect. Using 'Show Desktop' from the TaskBar will over-ride any non-focused application's attempts to make the window visible. This is by design.