# Achieve window minimize effect

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I minimize a window of a WPF application it gets minimized to Windows taskbar. I want to override this functionality to something like the minimize effect generated by `IDM download finished Window` which goes to left bottom of the screen but doesnot minimize to taskbar.

Adding a screenshot for better understanding.

[image]
How do I achieve this? Need some inputs to start.

Comment: I suppose it does not really minimize. It hooks the minimize event and then performs some animation which reduces its size. It does not actually perform a minimazation.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is a really good Idea- as I user I would REALLY love such annoying crap.
If you really want to do this: oveerride the minimizuing behaviour and canel it. Then show a new window which has the few controls you are needing and put it in an annoying location.

Comment: @Samuel: Yes that's true. So is it like I apply some storyboard animation to the Window on the minimize event and reduce its size and change its position to get this result?

Comment: @ChristianSauer: My Application is a full screen application which will not even display taskbar to the user. So if a user minimizes any child window of the home screen then he will not be able to access it since taskbar is invisible. So I would like to go with this approach!! Can you suggest any better solution ?

Comment: You're describing [*MDI*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22927/Multiple-Window-Interface-for-WPF) functionality. Don't invent a wheel..

Comment: @AnatoliiGabuza: Sadly WPF doesn't support MDI. :(

Comment: Afaik WPF is not desiged for MDI. And catching the state changing (not state changed) event is quite tricky: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926758/window-statechanging-event-in-wpf

Comment: Sounds absolutely horrific... NEVER try and override functionality the user would expect. When will developers realise it harms their apps.

Comment: An alterantive would be to provide custom dialog buttons in terms of hiding the standard ones and providing your own and then apply an animation on the position and size of the element.

Comment: @Nilesh: Don't hide the taskbar?!

Comment: @ChristianSauer: Well the client requirement is that the taskbar should be hidden and only app should be visible. Can't really do much with that!! :(

Comment: This was possible easily to achieve in winforms. IFAIR do not show window in taskbar and then minimizing it will do this. No idea about wpf. And no idea why would anyone want this crap (it is really annoying to users, please use another way to achieve whatever you are trying to).