# Allow resizing while keeping scale proportions on Window

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, resize, window

I want to have a window that the User can resize, and I want this window to keep the scale proportions (MVVM way if it is possible !).

I have two different approaches:

- Handling the `SizeChangedEvent` and adjust `Width` or `Height`. Worked but the Window had really weird animations while resizing.
- Handling the `MouseUp` event, to adjust `Width` or `Height` when the User releases the button (when resizing). Unfortunately, the `MouseUp` event doesn't trigger when you release the LeftButton after resizing. I couldn't use `MouseBinding` because `MouseGesture` doesn't have a "MouseUp" parameter, only a `LeftClick`!

Can you help me, giving me advice, code, links or anything useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approch you are taking is correct, another way is to use `win32 interop` as explained in following posts -

http://blog.mikeobrien.net/2009/09/maintaining-aspect-ratio-when-resizing.html

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b0df3d1f-e211-4f54-a079-09af0096410e

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/77b566aa-be88-47a4-8c29-b1e44946348e/

Other similar SO threads -

[How Can I Only Allow Uniform Resizing in a WPF Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386484/how-can-i-only-allow-uniform-resizing-in-a-wpf-window)

[Resize a WPF window, but maintain proportions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471867/resize-a-wpf-window-but-maintain-proportions)

but it will be tough to get rid of flickering effect altogether.